# how to manage translations in salesforce for the application running outside salesforce?

Tags: apex, javascript, integration, translation, web-components

We are developing an application that will be deployed on a web platform.The backend data is stored in salesforce and what we would like to do is to support multi lingual app. Is there a way where the form labels will get translated based on some code/setting within salesforce and the values will be accessed on the application outside salesforce? For example - if the attribute value passed to the component is 'French' , all the form labels and buttons would get translated to French language. Similarly it translates any languages dynamically as long as it is translated in Salesforce.
Is this possible or any suggestions on this?

Comment: Thank you @PhilW for the suggested article but it doesn't resolve my problem as toLabel() is used only for picklist values/record type names, my ask is to be able to translate form labels/texts, button labels.

Comment: My point was actually about the use of Accept-Language header. If you are using a REST API, setting this header when you invoke it will automatically apply localization using that specified language. Look at the third answer.